# How to show a text field upon hovering a button with just pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, button, hover

Is there a way to only use pure CSS code to show a text field when you hover a button?

```
<form id="demo">
    <input type="text" id="search-field" name="s" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" id="search-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</form>
```

The text field should be hidden and only shows up when you hover the button. I'm not sure it can be done through CSS only. :/

Comment: which field would you like to show on hover?

Comment: This looks like a usability nightmare. In the provided answers, you can't even click on the text field (though you can tab to it). Where are all these upvotes coming from?

Answer (score 10):

Try this code:

```css
#search-field {
    display: none;
}
#btn:hover + #search-field {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form id="demo">
    <input type="button" value="Hover" id="btn" />
    <input type="text" id="search-field" name="s" placeholder="Search" />
    <input type="submit" id="search-icon" />
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</form>
```

**Updated**

Swap your inputs in the HTML and rearrange your elements using the `order` property and apply `display:flex;` to your container in CSS. That would solve it.

```css
#search-field {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#search-icon:hover + #search-field {
    visibility: visible;
}
#demo {
    display: flex;
}
input:nth-child(2) {
    order: -1;
}
```

```html
<form id="demo">
    <input type="submit" id="search-icon" />
    <input type="text" id="search-field" name="s" placeholder="Search" />
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</form>
```

Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/5336321

Comment: It works given with that new input. But can this work, #btn:hover + #search-field{ visibility:visible;} using the "submit" input type?

Comment: There are no selectors to do that in css but you can do this using flex and reversing the order https://jsfiddle.net/b7snbomk/ or use JS or jQuery

Comment: @user12109321358 you can place `submit` button before `input`

Comment: check my updated answer if that could help you get after this!

Comment: you can do as suggested by @Muhammad Usman if you're not bothered about the positions

Comment: Just gave up on my codepen... about 30 lines of code and getting there... you do it in like 8... haha nice job

Comment: Glad you value it @Ricky :)

Comment: Hitesh, thank you!! That worked!! And now I know how flex and order really works. :P Thanks!! :)

Comment: Nice, but why you used `input:nth-child(2)` instead of just `#search-field`. I didn't understand that part.

Comment: The input fields have 2 different ids so i triggered with the element selector `input`. instead you can use a class with same name `.class_name:nth-child(2)`

Comment: By the way, do the inputs need to be swapped?

Answer (score 2):

You can swap the order of `input[type="text"]` and `input[type="submit"]` and then you can style `input[type="text"]` on hover of button as shown below.

```css
#demo {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
#search-field {
  transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#search-icon:hover + #search-field {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form id="demo">
  <input type="submit" id="search-icon" />
  <input type="text" id="search-field" name="s" placeholder="Search" />
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</form>
```